# Passing data through tabs in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Using ActionBar Sherlock to implements tabs, I have a new TabsAdapter object declared and two tabs added to it.

```
mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, getSupportActionBar(), mViewPager);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab1, FragmentA.class);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab2, FragmentB.class);
```

There is some data in a hashmap that i would need to use in both FragmentA and FragmentB. Both these classes extend the android Fragment. I am not sure how to pass this data and retrieve it at the other end.

Thank you for the help

Comment: the hashmap is actually passed from one activity to the activity that the fragment is attached to using the putExtra method. my current solution is to retrieve it using `this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().get("value")` within each fragment. Not sure if this is the best workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep this data in activity in a class level field and access it from both the fragments.

A Fragment has access to activity instance using getActivity() method.